# when I run flutter build apk command in android studio I get AndroidX incompatibilities issue

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am running this command in android studio to build an apk but I am getting this error "The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app." I try mulitple things but problem is still there how can I solve this issue

```
C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports>flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Initializing gradle...                                              1.4s
Resolving dependencies...                                           4.7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\U
sers\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\bg.png', attempting to stop daemon.

  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 56s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           57.1s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
See <link here > for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: well, what did you try?

Comment: Please share the things that you have tried to solve this so that we do not repeat ourselves.  Also, I assume you have visited the link mentioned in the error message at the bottom.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutter-community/solving-androidx-error-in-flutter-89bdc45885a6

Comment: check out this article on medium it may help you

Comment: I have set 
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true 
into gradle.properties  this file I even try to avoid android X by following this article https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: I found an error in my problem by my self that is drawable\bg.png  image is disturbing I do not know for the reason but I removed that image now all previous errors gone Even Android X compatibility error is solve but I have new Error now

Comment: C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:304: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found
.

  C:\Users\Waqas\AndroidStudioProjects\gtvsports\build\firebase_admob\intermediates\res\merged\release\values\values.xml:305: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidX is officially released by Google and it is having some compatibility issues with frameworks like Flutter. So, you must follow the Flutter website link given below for the same.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

I am sure this will solve your issue.